# How to reference chart ID that is stored in string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am passing a string variable `chartName` that contains the ID of a chart I am trying to reference. The contents of this string is always something like `Chart1`, `Chart2`, `Chart3`. How can I pull the chart ID out of the string so I can use it to add data points to the chart?

The following code obviously does not work since `chartName` is a string variable and there is no chart ID named `chartName`:

```
chartName.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(series1data);
```

My goal is to perform something like this:

```
"Contents of chartName".Series["Series1"].Points.Add(series1data);
```

which should look like:

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(series1data);
```

Comment: `(this.FindControl(chartName) as Chart).Series`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get an Object reference not set error when I run your code and also when I run this: `(this.FindControl("Chart1") as Chart).Series["Series1"].Points.Add(series1data);`. They both should be passing the chart name...not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: `this.FindControl` will search in page container and just top controls, so if your charts are placed in PlaceHolder\GridView\Repeater\other container control, then you need to search inside them, like `placeHolder1.FindControl(chartName)`

Comment: Ahhh, yes! This chart is located within a Script Manager. The following code works: `(SCManager.FindControl(chartName) as Chart).Series` Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(this.FindControl(chartName) as Chart).Series` is what I used to resolve this.

Thank you, Sergey Litvinov!